# How to select the content in the span tag of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the code from which I want to get the elements, I used the code

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
```

I got all the elements of class 'highlight' but I want to select all the elements which are having 'Green Leafy veggies' in the span tag with class as highlight only.

```
<html>

<body>
  <style>
    .highlight {
      color: blue;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .highlight2 {
      color: green;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  <p>This is the health benefits of <span class='highlight'>Green leafy veggies</span> hope you kids eat them.</p>

  <p>This is the health benefits of <span class='highlight2'>Green leafy veggies</span> hope you kids eat them.</p>
  <p>This is the health benefits of <span class='highlight'>Green leafy veggies</span> hope you kids eat them.</p>
  <p>This is another <span class='highlight'>Green leafy veggies</span>tag</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an array out of the elements' collection (use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for it), and use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the desired elements:

```js
var elements =

  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('highlight'))
  .filter(element => element.innerText === 'Green leafy veggies');

console.log(elements.length);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight2 {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the health benefits of <span class='highlight'>Red leafy veggies</span> hope you kids eat them.</p>

<p>This is the health benefits of <span class='highlight2'>Green leafy veggies</span> hope you kids eat them.</p>
<p>This is the health benefits of <span class='highlight'>Green leafy veggies</span> hope you kids eat them.</p>
<p>This is another <span class='highlight'>Green leafy veggies</span>tag</p>
```

**Edit 1**

To find all the elements containing the text *leafy*, you can just replace `element.innerText === 'Green leafy veggies'` with `/leafy/.test(element.innerText)`.

Comment: how to implement querySelectorAll method to the elements array

Comment: @vamsi -- Please ask a new question with your requirements. Let this answe be focused to the original question to limit its scope. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned jQuery tag

You can go with [contains](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/)

```
var elements = $('.highlight:contains("Green leafy veggies")');
```